# How do you search for special characters in a substring SQL

Tags: sql

Hi basically i have a column for payment,  its either 0, a $[amt] or [amt]%, how do i search for substring that contains the %? right now i am just doing

`select * from table where not Payment like '$%' and not Payment =0`

to retrieve all the rows that contains a % in the substring

Comment: Did you remove the SQLite tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original question tagged with SQLite.
You can use `ESCAPE` (find more here [SQL As Understood By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)):

```
select * from tablename where Payment like '%#%' ESCAPE '#'
```

The character immediately following the escaped character `'#'` is treated as a string literal and not as a wildcard char.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q7k2Q3vyhycsN6QeyWJ3pc/1).

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    Payment TEXT
);
INSERT INTO tablename (Payment) VALUES 
 ('0'),
 ('15%'),
 ('$55'),
 ('3%');
```

Results:

```
| Payment |
| ------- |
| 15%     |
| 3%      |
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try  using %\%   (escaping %)

```
select * from table where not Payment like '%\%' and not Payment =0
```

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL 5.6**

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    PAYMENT 
WHERE 
    AMOUNT NOT LIKE '$\%%' 
AND 
    CONVERT(SUBSTRING(AMOUNT, 2), SIGNED INTEGER) = 0;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6fbfb/1)

**Oracle 11g R2**

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
    PAYMENT 
WHERE 
    AMOUNT NOT LIKE '$\%%' 
AND
    SUBSTR(AMOUNT, 2) LIKE '0' ESCAPE '\';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/160db0/15)